# How to find all ways that the group $A_5$ act on a set of three elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I want to find all ways that the group $A_5$ acting on a set of 3 elements and what can be the orbit size?

My attempt: I thinking it is same as finding all the homomorphism into $S_3$. $S_3$ has six elements and it is non-abelian.

The group $A_5$ is simple group so there is no nontrivial normal subgroup. Kernel of homomorphism is normal so it's either the identity or the whole group $A_5$.

So if there is a homomorphism, then it's either injective or trivial.

Since $A_5$ has $60$ elements then any homomorphism is trivial. So the action is trivial.

The orbit size in this case is one.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how could you get a comment of 4 letters only, @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez?

Comment: @Devo, just end the comment with `${}{}{}{}$`, etc., until you get enough characters.